# cusp point of a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry

Suppose that $r=r(x,y)$, $s=s(x,y)$ is $C^3$ in a neighborhood $(0,0)$, where $r$,$s$ and all partial derivate in $(0,0)$ is $(0,0)$. Prove that $(0,0)$ is an isolated singular point of the system:

$$x'=y+r(x,y) \ \ y'=x^2+kxy+s(x,y), k\in \mathbb{R}$$

and prove that there is a unique curve, $C^1$, $y=A(x)$ defined in $[0,\epsilon]$ that a solution of the system goes to $(0,0)$ when $t\to \infty$ if only if the solution intercept $y=A(x)$.

I tried to see firstly the case where $k=0$ and $r=0=s$ but i didn't had an ideia, i think that i need to use implicit theorem function... To prove that $(0,0)$ is a singular point, do i need see the jacobian in $(0,0)$? I am not sure if it helps... How can i concluded that is an isolated point?

Comment: If i show that, choose polar coordinates $x=r^2cos\theta$, $y=r^3sen\theta$ (i have two saddle points), so can i conclude something about this?